# How to hide NSFW commands from help menu if the channel isn't NSFW

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a help menu and some commands in it. There are some NSFW commands too and I want these commands to not show if the channel isn't marked as NSFW.

Here is my current code:

```js
case 'help':
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
  if (message.content.startsWith(';')) {
    const embed10 = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
    embed10.setColor([133, 0, 255]);
    embed10.setTitle('Command List');
    embed10.addField(
      ' Emotes',
      '`smile` `sad` `cry` `sleepy` `angry` `happy` `blush` `baka` `confused` `pout` `die` `scared` `laugh` `bai` `run` `drunk` `eat` `drink` `hungry` `facepalm`',
    );
    embed10.addField(
      ' NSFW',
      '`rhentai` `ngif` `wallpaper` `feet` `boobs` `ahegao`',
    );
    embed10.addField(
      ' Utility',
      '`botinfo` `weather` `uptime` `say` `hammer` `advice` `vibingcat`  `bongo` `ping` `Axmyo` `drawing`',
    );

    message.channel.send(embed10);
  }
  break;
```

Comment: How does your current help command look like?

Comment: It's too long, read it here: https://justpaste.it/87aka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`nsfw` property](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=nsfw) on the `message.channel` which you can check and based on that you can add the NSFW field:

```js
switch (command) {
  case 'help':
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
    if (message.content.startsWith(';')) {
      const embed10 = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
      embed10.setColor([133, 0, 255]);
      embed10.setTitle('Command List');
      embed10.addField(
        ' Emotes',
        '`smile` `sad` `cry` `sleepy` `angry` `happy` `blush` `baka` `confused` `pout` `die` `scared` `laugh` `bai` `run` `drunk` `eat` `drink` `hungry` `facepalm`',
      );
      if (message.channel.nsfw) {
        embed10.addField(
          ' NSFW',
          '`rhentai` `ngif` `wallpaper` `feet` `boobs` `ahegao`',
        );
      }
      embed10.addField(
        ' Utility',
        '`botinfo` `weather` `uptime` `say` `hammer` `advice` `vibingcat`  `bongo` `ping` `Axmyo` `drawing`',
      );

      message.channel.send(embed10);
    }
    break;
}
```